# Как и где правильно сделать множественную выборку из коллекции?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Есть Web Api на Asp. Net и под него пишу клиент. Задача такова: Пользователь задает некие критерии отбора и программа должна отобразить найденные эти данные (логический AND). Встал вопрос реализации. Изначально запрашиваю все данные из таблицы и загоняю их в типизированную по модели коллекцию. Первые вопрос: Где лучше реализовать в Web Api или в клиенте выборку из коллекции? Второй вопрос: Как? В клиенте я асинхронно запрашиваю все данные из таблицы и уже могут делать выбору, но встал вопрос, как правильно сделать такую множественную выборку? (Пока мучаю лямбды и пытаюсь выстроить логику передачи параметров для выборки).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, фильтрацию результатов нужно осуществлять на сервере. Клиенту совсем ни к чему знать ВСЕ значения, хранящиеся в базе. Также передача всей выборки сильно загрузит интернет-канал, а фильтрация большой по объёму выборки может сильно загрузить клиента.

Насчёт собственно фильтрации. Откуда вы данные вытягиваете? Наверняка из какой-нибудь базы данных. Так не проще ли составить правильный SQL-запрос, который ещё на этапе выборки из базы отсеет лишние результаты?

Если по каким-либо причинам вариант "грамотно составить запрос" вам не подходит, вот способ фильтрации списка. Сразу оговорюсь, я почти уверен, что существует более красивое/правильное/простое, но я до него не додумался. В классе `List` есть замечательный метод `Where`, который позволяет отсеивать из списка лишние результаты. В него передаётся делегат, который принимает значение типа элементов списка, а возвращает `bool` (`true` если нужно оставить элемент, `false` если нет). Вот простой пример:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SampleNamespace
{
    public class SampleClass
    {
        private static Func<int, bool> gt(int val) {
            return (i => i > val);
        }

        private static Func<int, bool> lt(int val) {
            return (i => i < val);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            List<int> items = new List<int>();
            items.Add(1);
            items.Add(2);
            items.Add(3);
            items.Add(4);
            items.Add(5);
            items.Add(6);

            List<int> result = new List<int>(items.Where(gt(2)).Where(lt(5)));

            foreach (int i in result) {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример максимально упрощён. Функции `lt` и `gt` генерируют делегаты, которые проверяют, является ли переданное значение меньше (больше) заданной константы. Вам скорее всего понадобятся функции сравнения посложнее. Так как все ваши условия объединяются логическим И, то для достижения требуемого эффекта можно просто последовательно применять к выборке условия. В общих чертах идея состоит в том, чтобы написать достаточное количество генераторов функций сравнения, а затем в соответствии с запросом пользователя применять их к выборке.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Идея ясна. 
Да, используется Sql-server, есть модель данных, через контекст данных контроллер заполняет коллекцию по модели данными. Так что использование SQL-запросов не очень уместно. Буду пробовать реализовать Вашу идею.